# How to make PHP pages dynamic?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, dynamic

I recently created a website where a user logs in and accesses various forms and other things.  I was wondering, after login, how can I change the php code so that it automatically modifies a portion of the page making it personal?  Here is a screen shot of the front end.

I would like the login form portion disappear and then have a new layout replace it.  Would I use Javascript or AJAX.  If either, does anyone have any guidance on how to go about doing this project?

[image]

Comment: You'll never get any work done on Facebook :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like one of your goals is to minimize page refreshes, possibly having none at all.

Your main challenges include:
1. Managing possibly lots of unrelated DIVs, which make up your functional segments. 
2. Speed issues - lots of code crammed into one page.
3. All input sent asynchronously (things get complicated very fast when you want to do EVERYTHING with AJAX!)

As far as your initial login menu, you can fade that out by wrapping it in a DIV and calling jQuery's fadeOut() function on it. To update PHP components without refresh, that's where your AJAX comes in. You're going to want to use a little of each and like therealsix said, they're all essentially Javascipt at the core.

My best advice would be to spend a big chunk of your time dedicated to this project in the planning stage.  Understand how you are going to deal with DIVs crashing into each other. Develop an overall table layout that gives you flexibility concerning where content DIVs come in and out. Think about which ones are replaceable at any given time. Study up on modular coding.

That's broad advice because I don't know what exactly the project entails, so if you have any specific issues, let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't you end up having lots of crammed up code even when you have 1 page application. There are library like [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) which will help you separate your code properly. Also things shouldn't get complicated if you do everything in Ajax. If it becomes complicated, it's most likely because you got the architecture of your application wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would say neither. If you're going to change the whole page, just redirect to a new page.

If you needed to do this without a page reload you would need to use javascript and AJAX (ajax in some sense is javascript). Then I would recommend you look at the jquery functions (http://api.jquery.com/load/)